How to output a file without light but there is light?
I put a photo of a landscape on a plane and when I want to output it, I have to add light, but I want the photo to have the same light without adding light when I output it. how can i do
Or, for example, how to get an output that even if we add light, there is no shadow?
I use Blender to design graphic user interfaces for websites or games, and the result is much better than Figma, Photoshop, or Illustrator.
Blender is God

Can you elaborate on what exactly you're trying to achieve? It sounds like you might be trying to have an image plane consistently emit light to prevent shadows from occurring, in which case you could set the plane to use an emission material.

...like Christopher said. Or you could plug the texture directly into the Material Output, this works as if you use an Emission, only that you cannot change the strength. But it works as if the strength was 1, which is what you need to display the texture as is without shadows.
